# ROS Answers SE migration: robot_pose_ekf

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, odom-combined, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
I'm using turtlebot, distro hydro,i did the stack navigation with odometry, now i want working with odom-combined (robot_pose_ekf), is there anyone who did that, can help me.i didn't know what changes do I need to do.
Is what I have to change all odometry term to  odom_combined term, and remove the transformation between odom and  base-footprint since robot poses ekf node will make the transformation between odom_combined and base-footprint
Any help please !

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207438/robot_pose_ekf/) by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your response  :)
what I understood so the only role of the robot_poses_ekf   is the transformation which he offers between odom combined and basefootprint.
So in the stack navigating we didn't need to work with odom_combined ? we must keep the odom parameter (for example for the local costmap in the global_frame)
in fact my work is to compare two trajectories done by a robot one with Odom and the other with the odom_combined.

---

Originally posted by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) with karma: 53 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to make sure that you are consistent with the odometry term, does not matter if it is odom or odom_combined as long as it is same throughout.
Yes, you do not have to provide the transformation, robot_pose_ekf will do that.
Check this out : http://answers.ros.org/question/11682/robot_pose_ekf-with-an-external-sensor/

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-21**:
Thanks for your response :) what I understood so the only role of the robot_poses_ekf is the transformation which he offers between odom combined and basefootprint. So in the stack navigating we didn't need to work with odom_combined ? we must keep the odom parameter (for example for the local costm